# Can't inject a sessionScoped managedBean into other managedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a sessionScoped Bean which needs to be be injected in other beans.

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(eager = true, name="signBundle")
public class SignBundleBean implements Serializable{
    private ArrayList<Signing> selectedDownloads;
    private ArrayList<Signing> selectedSignings;
    private ArrayList<Signing> signings = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Signing> downloads = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> parameterColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    private int maxParameters = 0;
```

I am trying to inject this bean into other bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadView implements Serializable {  

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{signBundle}")
    private SignBundleBean signBundleBean; 

    static String codesignRoot = InitialisationHelper.getCodesignRoot();
    transient Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
    ArrayList<Signing> signings = signBundleBean.getSignings();
```

I am getting exception because signBundle is not initialised and is null.

```
Cant instantiate class: com.oracle.ccss.web.beans.FileUploadView.
javax.faces.FacesException: Cant instantiate class:    com.oracle.ccss.web.beans.FileUploadView.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
...
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.oracle.ccss.web.beans.FileUploadView.
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.oracle.ccss.web.beans.FileUploadView.<init>(FileUploadView.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
at com.oracle.ccss.web.beans.FileUploadView.<init>(FileUploadView.java:43)
```

As hinted by `<init>`, that `NullPointerException` is thrown from constructor of `FileUploadView` bean. You seem to be doing as follows in the constructor:

```
public FileUploadView() {
    signBundleBean.doSomething();
}
```

You seem to expect that Java is somehow able to do the following:

```
FileUploadView fileUploadView;
fileUploadView.setSignBundleBean(signBundle);
fileUploadView = new FileUploadView();
```

This is untrue. It works as follows:

```
FileUploadView fileUploadView;
fileUploadView = new FileUploadView();
fileUploadView.setSignBundleBean(signBundle);
```

If you intend to work on `signBundle` directly after construction, then you should be doing the job in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method instead.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    signBundleBean.doSomething();
}
```

JSF will automatically call it directly after construction **and** managed property setting.